# SwiftUI spring animation issue

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

When I use spring animation, you can see that the `Giriş başarısız` text remains inactive. This text comes from the backend. When I give a static value, the animation does not break, but when I give a dynamic value, why does it break the animation?

[image]

**Onboarding View:**

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    @State var isHasError: Bool = false
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ....
            LoginView(isHasError: $isHasError, errorMessage: $errorMessage, isSelectedRegister: $isSelectedRegister)
            ErrorView(isShownBadge: $isHasError, errorMessage: $errorMessage)
                .offset(y: isHasError ? .zero : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0), value: isHasError)
        }
    }
}
```

**Login View:**

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    enum LoginField {
        case username
        case password
    }
    
    @State var userName: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Binding var isHasError: Bool
    @Binding var errorMessage: String
    @Binding var isSelectedRegister: Bool
    @FocusState private var focusedField: LoginField?
    @StateObject private var viewModel =       LoginViewModel(yourAIAssistantRespository: .prod)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                ....
                
                CustomButton(title: "Giriş Yap", buttonColor: .aiBlue, textColor: .white) {
                    Task(priority: .userInitiated) {
                        await viewModel.fetchLogin(with: .init(userName: userName, password: password))
                    }
                }
            }
            .disabled(isSelectedRegister ? true : false)
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .blur(radius: isLoading ? 10 : 0)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0), value: isLoading)
            
            Group {
                switch viewModel.state {
                case .loading:
                    LottieView(name: .loading)
                        .onAppear {
                            isLoading = true
                        }
                case .fail(error: let error):
                    Text("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .na:
                    EmptyView()
                case .loginResult:
                    EmptyView()
                        .onReceive(viewModel.$state, perform: { newValue in
                            isLoading = false
                            if case .loginResult(let response) = newValue {
                                if let hasError = response.hasError {
                                    isHasError = hasError
                                    errorMessage = response.message ?? ""
                                }
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error View:**

```
struct ErrorView: View {
    @Binding var isShownBadge: Bool
    @Binding var errorMessage: String
    var body: some View {

            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Hata ⚠️")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title)
                    Text(errorMessage)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            isShownBadge = false
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.square")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .frame(height: 70)
            .padding(.vertical)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.aiBlue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the backend code that gets the error message? is it asynchronous?

Comment: I added Login View

Answer (score 1):

If you change this ZStack for a VStack

```
struct ErrorView: View {
    @Binding var isShownBadge: Bool
    @Binding var errorMessage: String
    var body: some View {

            // ZStack {
            VStack {
    ...
```

Comment: no sir. same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).